# draw polyline between two latitude and longitude

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift3, mkpolyline

I pass two lat and long for source and destination but not draw poly line between two point.always get something wrong error  .below code I pass my current location in source coordinate and travel location pass in destCoordinates. I want draw poly line between sourceCoordinates to destCoordinates..

```
  if(CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()){
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    //let sourceCoordinates = locationManager.location?.coordinate


      let sourceCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(19.115950,72.856448)
    let destCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(19.119670,72.853616)
    let sourcePlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: sourceCoordinates)
         let destPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destCoordinates)

    let sourceItem = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlacemark)
    let destItem = MKMapItem(placemark: destPlacemark)

    let directionRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()

    directionRequest.source=sourceItem
    directionRequest.destination=destItem



    directionRequest.transportType = .walking
    let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)
    directions.calculate(completionHandler: {
    response,error in
        guard let response = response else{

           if let error = error {
            print("something wrong")
            }
            return
        }
        let route = response.routes[0]
        self.upcoming_info_map.add(route.polyline,level: .aboveRoads)
        let rekt = route.polyline.boundingMapRect
        self.upcoming_info_map.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(rekt), animated: true)

    })
```

for draw polyline i use this function

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    let renderer = MKPolygonRenderer(overlay:overlay)
    renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
    renderer.lineWidth = 5.0
    return renderer
}
```

Comment: Did you set the delegate

Comment: if you print out the error it clearly says "walking directions not available" so change the direction type and check

Comment: for india directions not available in apple maps try some other lat and long

Answer (score 0):

use this method.takes list of locations and draw polyline

```
    func addPolyLineToMap(googlemaplist: [CLLocation?]){


    var coordinates = googlemaplist.map({ (location: CLLocation!) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D in
        return location.coordinate
    })

    print("locatios count")
    print(googlemaplist.count)

    var polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &coordinates, count: googlemaplist.count)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.MapKit.add(polyline)

    }
}
```